# USB ports only works with mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows, group-policy, usb-storage

So i joined this company and they had a specialist before that disabled all the usb ports to prevent people from using external devices such as external hard drives, phones CDs... Only 2 ports work just for mouse and keyboard.
And now i need to get them to work again, as of just now i checked the registry editor (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM |CurrentControllSet | Services | USBSTOR but the value of "start" was already "3".
I also tried the group policy editor in computer configuration > Administrative Templates > System > removable Storage
All of them were not configured but i disabled them and still they don't work.
If anyone knows any other method i would appreciate it.

Comment: Check the device manager what new device is displayed when you plug-in e.g. an USB-stick. Also check the driver that is used on this new device. May be a wrong driver was installed willfully to disable drive access. Alternatively you can simply re.install the PC and make a fresh start on an unmanipulated system.

Comment: I just tried with an external hard drive and it said that the setup has been blocked by group policy.